# adding new key value in javascript array not affecting

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have `array` like this,

```
var serialize={};
```

Now, i have form and i am serializing that form and adding that to `serialize` in array like this,

```
var c=12;
ser[c]=$(elem).find('input[name!=material_id],select').serializeArray();
```

Which generates array like this,

```
ser[127][0][name]   quantity_1_127
ser[127][0][value]  100
ser[127][1][name]   single_1_127
ser[127][1][value]  11
ser[127][2][name]   double_1_127
ser[127][2][value]  17.5
```

Now i just want to insert new key and value and i am doing it like this

```
ser[c]['test']='test';
```

But which is not affecting. What is the reason of this? Am i doing anything wrong here? Any alternate solution?

Comment: You need to use `ser[c].push({'name':'foo','value':'bar'});`

Comment: That's not an array by the way, it's an object as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: @FaustoNA actually it's array of objects with name and value keys

Comment: @jcubic did same but it inserting with new number key, i want to make own key

Comment: you want to get rid of all the ser[127][0][name] elements and replace them with ser[127].test for example?

Comment: @TudorConstantin sorry but not getting you exact.

Answer (score 1):

That's because `ser[c]` is an array and you are trying to use it as an object.

Add that test/test thing with:

```
ser[c].push({'test': 'test'});
```

Or, as your other values in the object are set:

```
ser[c].push({ 'name': 'test', 'value': 'test'});
```

This is not PHP where your indices in an associative array can be either strings or integers. This is javascript, where, if your indices in an object are integer, than that object is an array and if your indices are strings, your object is an ... well, object.

So, if you want to have something like `ser[c]['mykey'] = value`, you'll have to do something like:

```
ser[c] = { 'mykey': 'value'};
```

But this means that the `ser[127][0]` type of elements will be gone.

Comment: yes that did job, but issue is, its creating new number key like this, `[88] => Array
                (
                    [test] => test
                )`

Comment: And what exactly do you want this to create in the end? Try the second version and see if that does what you need

Comment: I just want like this at the end `ser[127][2][value]  17.5 ---- ser[127]['mykey'][value]  'my value'`

Comment: "*if your indices in an object are integer, than that object is an array*" - that's not how arrays work. Arrays are special objects of which only integer indices are used.

Comment: @Bergi - I over simplified, in order to help him achieve what he wants.

Comment: any way to do this by merging array? or any other?